# Merging two rasters into one image mosaic using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, image-mosaic

I would like to merge two raster into one image. Both rasters have value range different from each other. On one hand, the values range from  (Image 1) 21.5 to 15.7. One the other hand are 18.15 to 13.3 (Image 2).

Image 1 is found outside of Image 2 and they do not have overlapping areas. But I want both images to be displayed as one with the same value range and color ramp.

I am using ArcGIS 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I did.

1. Convert both images to points making sure that the output pixels contain the same information as the input raster.
2. Merge both point shapefiles into a single output.
3. Interpolate the points.
4. Clip to desired geometry.

Answer (score 2):

changing the both raster value range you can check out:

1. Reclassify (Spatial Analyst), [here](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009z000000sr000000.htm)

> Reclassifies (or changes) the values in a raster.

2. Synchronize Mosaic Dataset (Data Management), [here](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Synchronize_Mosaic_Dataset/00170000008v000000/)

> Rebuilds the raster item and updates affected fields in the mosaic
>   dataset using the raster type and options that were used when it was
>   originally added.

beside this you should glance at Raster toolset for your needs.

Answer (score 2):

Using ArcCatalog, copy one of the rasters to a folder somewhere.  This will be the output raster.  Rename the output raster.  Then use the mosaic tool to mosaic the second raster to the existing output raster.